# Rails Strong Parameters raise exception or log per controller setting?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, strong-parameters

From combing the documentation, the only place I can see to configure Strong Parameters raise or log setting is via:

```
config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :raise
```

I'm wanting to set this to `:raise` for my Public API Controllers so that I can use:

```
  rescue_from ActionController::UnpermittedParameters do |e|
    render json: {error: e.message, params: e.params}, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
```

So that API consumers can understand what is wrong with their request and fix accordingly.

But for other controllers, I'd rather the un-permitted parameters be logged (and fail silently) as to not break things unnecessarily for any malicious inserting form fields into the DOM. Can this be done? If I add the rescue in those controllers,  then the update would be aborted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this with something like the following:

```
white_list = [:name, :job, :id]

params.reject! {|k,_| !white_list.include?(k)}
```

Comment: But this will interrupt the update. I want to be able to continue updating the record, ignoring the un-permitted parameters instead of raising an exception